# getAlbumName() and getAlbumDir() in capturing a photo Android

Tags: android

Im reading the android documentation and I cant tie things together.
in the examples below, some methods are called that dont exist

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

First of all, where should I place this piece of code:

```
storageDir = new File (
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + PICTURES_DIR
        + getAlbumName()
);
```

Second, what does the getAlbumName() method consist of?

Then here:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName, 
        JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, 
        getAlbumDir()
    );
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

getAlbumDir() - where is this coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAlbumName()` is the name of the album the pictures are in, it is required to complete the file to the picture for `File f = new File(path to file)` This is being chosen by you effectively. You could use :

```
/* Photo album for this application */
private String getAlbumName() {
    return getString(R.string.album_name);
}
```

where `R.string.album_name` is chosen by you

The

```
storageDir = new File (
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    + PICTURES_DIR
    + getAlbumName()
);
```

should be in a function `getAlbumDir()` which is called in the next bit of code in the tutorial ...

```
File image = File.createTempFile(
    imageFileName, 
    JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, 
    getAlbumDir()
);
```

Comment: I just worked through the code in this google example and I'm confused about one thing that is related to this question. The storageDir() is a function of mAlbumStorageDirFactory where mAlbumStorageDirFactory is determined by the SDK version you are using. In the code, we see:   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
   mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
  } else {
   mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory(); I don't agree with this logic because the if our current SDK is greater than FROYO, we should be using BaseAlbumDirFactory().

Comment: Currently, we are using FroyoAlbumDirFactory() which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

To know full implementation of all functions you can download source code for the example.
[Sample Application](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/PhotoIntentActivity.zip)